# ui.bootstrap.timepicker not binding with angularjs ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I Am Using [ui.bootstrap.timepicker](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/timepicker) for creating and updating data via user Interaction.

The Timepicker is working well for creating data but it's not binding to the ng-model.

Here is a sample JSON array of the data passed to the Timepicker:

```
{
   "sort":1,
   "name":"Store Timings",
   "_id":"55b78a8658d3060e004fe9f2",
   "delivery":[
      {
         "open":"10:30",
         "close":"20:00",
         "leadTime":"45",
         "interval":"15",
         "message":"Accepting delivery orders",
         "_id":"55b78a8658d3060e004fe9f3",
         "isOpen":true
      }
   ],
   "pickup":[
      {
         "open":"09:30",
         "close":"20:30",
         "leadTime":"30",
         "interval":"15",
         "message":"Accepting takeot orders",
         "_id":"55b78a8658d3060e004fe9f4",
         "isOpen":true
      }
   ],
   "store":[
      {
         "open":"9:30 AM",
         "close":"10:30 PM",
         "message":"We are Open!",
         "_id":"55b78a8658d3060e004fe9f5",
         "isOpen":true
      }
   ],
   "isOnlineOrderOpen":true
}
```

As per the Above code I tried to render ng-value in to the Timepicker

Here is the HTML code:

```
<timepicker ng-model="sunday.store[0].open" hour-step="1" minute-step="15" show-meridian="true" ></timepicker>

<timepicker ng-model="sunday.store[0].close" hour-step="1" minute-step="15" show-meridian="true" ></timepicker>
```

This is showing that the Timepicker as Blank (I was expecting the values):-
 [image: blank Timepicker]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Timepicker is expecting you to pass in a Date object, not a string.

From the Timepicker [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/timepicker/docs)

> ng-model: The Date object that provides the time state.

I'm using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) to format my date from a string to a Date object.

See the [MomentJS parse documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

You can transform your times back to a string if required using the same library.